# What is the difference between "the ban on" and "the ban of"?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

What is the difference between *on* and *of* here:

1. the ban **on** door-to-door sales
2. the ban **of** door-to-door sales?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would say 'the ban on' and 'the banning of', myself. 'Of' is a "genitive concept" (often) and - in my view - is a verbal expression, in such cases (as long as it is not possessive). But I look forward to other comments/answers.

Comment: Thank you @Nigel J, that is helpful. A friend insists that by using "the ban on" it is saying that all door-to-door sales are banned but I maintain that to mean for all door-to-door sales to be banned I would say "the banning of door-to-door sales"  I would appreciate your comment as well as that of anyone else.